# DPDK: Zero Tx or Rx packets while runnning TestPMD

Tags: dpdk

I have setup DPDK 20.11. While running the basic TestPMD code, the number of Transmitted packets and received packets are zero. I need help and I am new to this.

I have attached the terminal screenshot of running TestPmd. I would like to know where I am making mistake.

[image]

[image]

OS: Ubuntu 16.04.6LTS (Xenial Xerus)

Testpmd was provided with no arguments (just gave 'sudo ./dpdk-testpmd' command)

Physical NIC
Firmware Details:
[The driver details and NIC firware has been provided in the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ipwip.png)

[Edit 1] [port info of first port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkENG.png)

[Port info of second port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26DvJ.png)

Comment: Please share OS, testpmd arguments, if in interactive mode the settings done, Is it vdev pr physical nic, Nic firmware and driver details and the screen shot. I am also flagging this as missing clarity and need more details too.

Comment: I have added the details you have asked in the post.

Comment: I am assuming you are sending packets, still you are not seeing packets on testpmd. If this is case run you run `start tx_first` in interactive shell of testpmd and check on Host side with tcpdump

Comment: @PranavVenkatesan are there any updates from your, if you are sending packets `01:00.0 and 06:00.1` then using `start tx_first or start` in testpmd interactive mode will allow packets to be send and received.

Comment: @Vipin Varghese I checked the port info of both the ports and found that the "Link Status: down" is displayed for both of the dpdk compatible drivers. Could this be the reason for no transmission of packets? If yes, how do I resolve this? (Screenshots included in Edit 1)

Comment: I think yes, you would need to check configuration nd setup. Will you be available on skype?

Comment: Yes, I am available.

Comment: ok I have been waiting, till now did not get call on the same

Comment: Vipin Sorry for not calling.. I notice in your profile that you live in India, but I am currently in Canada... So our timezone varies .. if you can tell me when your availablity in IST, I will definitely call you today..

Comment: I am availble now

Comment: @PranavVenkatesan I have already accepted and send you skype messages, still waiting on you. Now you have become offline. when you shared ` I notice in your profile that you live in India, but I am currently in Canada... So our timezone varies` I assumed you had by profile, but you did not. Then after accepting `chat invite` and waiting there is no update. So when time is right ping me on skype. happy to understand the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a live debug on the setup, The physical were not physically connected NIC or switch. In Linux Kernel `ethtool` the links are down. Hence in DPDK application, we get same message as `link Down`

Solution: connect the interfaces with either NIC or switch to get ports state up